# How to specify Exception when it doesn't seem to have a module?

Tags: ruby, exception

I've got some client code, in this example `MyModule`, that defines some custom Exceptions in a sub module called `Exception`. In `MyModule` there is a `rescue` block that references `Exception`. The problem is, ruby is resolving the name `Exception` to be `MyModule::Exception` (a module) when it needs to be the base Exception class from core ruby. Here's a code illustration to show what I mean:

```
puts Exception
puts Exception.class

module MyModule
    module Exception
        class CustomError < StandardError
        end
    end
end

module MyModule
    puts Exception
    puts Exception.class
end
```

The resulting output is:

```
Exception
Class
MyModule::Exception
Module
```

How can I force the second `Exception` reference to resolve to the core ruby `Exception` class when there is no module to distinguish it? I've tried Kernel::Exception and investigating whether there is a method to get the module its in, but there seems to only be `#name`, which produces the fully qualified name of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, you need to specify fully qualified name (FQN) for a class. Your exception has this FQN:

```
 MyModule::Exception
```

but Exception from core is on top level (not nested in anything), so its FQN is just

```
::Exception
```

And yes, you probably **don't want** to rescue core `Exception`. It's bad practice, because this handler will catch more things than you can handle (signals, load errors, etc)

Comment: I'll go with this one, since the boilerplate warning against umbrella catching is inevitably worthwhile.  In this case, it's code from my client, so I'm not entirely in charge of how its written. I agree that more specific Exception handling would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. On a lark, I tried `::Exception`, which makes a weird sort of sense.